# How to know which piece of code is the cause of an exception?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013

How is it possible to know which piece of code could cause the exception 'SPException was unhandled'?

### CODE:

```
SPList mylist = web.Lists.TryGetList("mylist"); 
SPListItem item = mylist.Items.Add(); 
... ... ... 

item.Update();
```

The trace is:

```
Stack details:
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bUnRestrictedUpdateInProgress, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, String bstrFileName, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pUniqueFieldCallback)
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.AddOrUpdateItem(Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystem, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Guid newGuidOnAdd, Int32& ulID, Object& objAttachmentNames, Object& objAttachmentContents, Boolean suppressAfterEvents, String filename, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion)
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.UpdateInternal(Boolean bSystem, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Guid newGuidOnAdd, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean suppressAfterEvents, String filename, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion)
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.Update()
       at Dumper.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\users\svcspfarm\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Dumper\Dumper\Program.cs:line 364
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: Another question would be how to actually read this post.

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am trying to add items in SPList mylist = web.Lists.TryGetList("mylist");
    SPListItem item = mylist.Items.Add();
    ...
    ...
    ...
    item.Update();  and getting this exception

Comment: So the question and code are now clearer, might be time to remove the downvotes?

Answer (score 0):

Look the sharepoint ULS logs to find out more information about exception.

```
\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS
```

For me it looks like you have not setup values for the required list fields.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these lines from stack trace:

```
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.Update()
  at Dumper.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\users\svcspfarm\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Dumper\Dumper\Program.cs:line 364
```

The exception is occurring on the call to `item.Update();`. I had a similar problem when I was attempting to add a subfolder to a list and it can be less than obvious what is causing the problem. I would hazard a guess that somewhere between your call to `mylist.Items.Add();` and the `Update()` that something has not been set correctly. A new list item may have some required fields that need to be initialised prior to the update?